# Moment does not calculate days correct, or am I wrong? ( I am but why )

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why would it be different?

incoming date `sDate = 2020-09-01`

```
fdate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, 'd').calendar(); //  =>  02/09/2020

fdate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(5, 'd').calendar(); // =>  Last Sunday at 12:00 AM
```

Why is 5 days not giving me `06/09/2020`?

I've tried this aswell. same thing

```
fdate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(5, "days").calendar();
```

Answer (score 1):

`calendar()` shows dates relative to some reference day (default today)... it's in the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

> Calendar time displays time relative to a given referenceDay (defaults
> to the start of today), but does so slightly differently than
> moment#fromNow.
>
> moment#calendar will format a date with different strings depending on
> how close to referenceDay's date (today by default) the date is.

```
Last week: Last Monday at 2:30 AM
The day before: Yesterday at 2:30 AM
The same day: Today at 2:30 AM 
The next day: Tomorrow at 2:30 AM 
The next week: Sunday at 2:30 AM
Everything else: 7/10/2011
```

If you want to format it explicitly, use `format()` instead of `calendar()`, e.g.:

```
moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(5, 'd').format('DD/MM/YYYYY')`
```

Comment: Sorry

`fdate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(7, "days").format('DD/MM/YYYY');`

This still results in `invalid date`

This is not working for 5 and 7 days. (the two Im checking)

Comment: @morne it seems to work for me, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cz4d1bqk/ . Are you sure the input date is correct as you wrote it in the question?

Comment: Yes 100% sure. I have tried in in the moment.js sandbox and it works there aswell. Im not sure why it reacts different in the program.

Comment: Maybe we are missing something... can you paste more of your code and tell how are you getting the initial date?

Comment: I have a form where you can select a start date.
Then there is a box to choose the interval for a reminder.
So the Start date comes in ( in this case ) as `'2020-09-01'` then I check which reminder interval to use in a switch.

7 days is the only one not calculating, I even tried it now as 
`fdate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, 'w').format('DD/MM/YYYY');`

Comment: Should I format the incoming string date different maybe? Works in the sandbox which is super weird.

Comment: Using `format` would result in different output. If there is still suspicion that calculation is incorrect, _update the question with supportive evidence and accurate context_ (ie. **don’t use** `calendar`). From the question, the calculation is correct as “last Sunday” (an artifact of `calendar` and _not_ `format`) was indeed 2020-09-06, which is 5d after 2020-09-01. — It might also be appropriate to create a new question and reset the non-related “last Sunday” artifact.

Comment: @morne sounds to me that your problem is different than what you are stating on the question (your question calculates correctly, yet doesn't output what you want (although correct, just not what you want), which is solved by using `format` instead of `calendar`... having an invalid date (not a problem with the actual output) is a completely different issue and would require different information